# Typescript type checking with a mixed member types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm working with Giphy's API with Typescript and the response give me a mixed media array of objects, something I can summarize like this:

```js
interface Type {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface Image extends Type {
  url: string;
}

interface Video extends Type {
  videoUrl: string;
}

interface Media {
  typeA: Image;
  typeB: Image & Video;
}
```

I created a `getUrl` function that allows the user to select the url setting the media type (`typeA` or `typeB`) and the url type (`url`  or `videoUrl`) but, as you can see, not all the combinations are valid (I can't select `videoUrl` for `typeA` media).

```js
const getUrl = (media, mediaType: 'typeA' | 'typeB', mediaUrl: 'url', 'videoUrl'): string => {
  return media[mediaType][mediaUrl];
};
```

This is facing me some typescript errors, like:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"url" | "videoUrl"' can't be used to index type 'Image | (Image & Video)'.
> Property 'videoUrl' does not exist on type 'Image | (Image & Video)'.ts(7053)

Can someone help me to improve the type checking and fixing the errors?

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/media-example-tgfxe?file=/src/MyComponent.tsx:644-683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slightly change `Props` interface:

```js
import * as React from "react";

interface Type {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

interface PropsA {
  mediaType: 'typeA';
  url: "url";
}

interface PropsB {
  mediaType: 'typeB';
  mediaUrl: 'videoUrl';
}

type Props = PropsA | PropsB


interface Image extends Type {
  url: string;
}

interface Video extends Type {
  videoUrl: string;
}

interface Media {
  typeA: Image;
  typeB: Image & Video;
}

const media: Media = {
  typeA: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    url: "my_url_01"
  },
  typeB: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    url: "my_url_02",
    videoUrl: "my_video_url_02"
  }
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const getUrl = () => {

    if (props.mediaType === 'typeA') {
      const x = props; // PropsA
      const { mediaType, url } = props;
      return media[mediaType][url]//[mediaType][mediaUrl];
    }
    const x = props; // PropsB
    const { mediaType, mediaUrl } = props;
    return media[mediaType][mediaUrl];

  };

  return <div>{getUrl()}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for typescript to distinguish union types, you need to type guard it. Can you try the following?

```
if(mediaType==='typeA') {
  return 'something';
} else {
  return media[mediaType][mediaUrl];
}
```